# Checking if a number can be written as a product of some fibonacci numbers

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, factorization

I have tried to solve the problem above but I got stuck. I guess that it all comes to factorization by non-prime numbers.  The number could be really big - about `10^15`.

What I attempted to do is to factor the x and all the Fibonacci numbers up to about 155th(this is the one that is over 10^30, and that means that I can not include its factors in my x's factors), then just like in normal factorization, I loop from the highest Fibonacci number to the lowest and check if my x has all the factors of the i-th Fibonacci number. If it does then I divide x by it. When I get to the i=1(I looped through all the Fibonacci factors table), I just check if my x is equal to 1. If it is, then my answer is YES, otherwise it is NO.

This solution **does not work**, because sometimes it **divides x in way which rules out further division**, so I tried to split it into two loops - the first one can divide the x by only Fibonacci numbers which have at least one number which does not belong to the Fibonacci sequence, and the second one can divide by every number.

**I took factored Fibonacci numbers from this website:** http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html

### **Here is an example which destroys the 1st idea:**

x=2^10 × 3^5 × 5^2 × 7 × 11 × 17 × 23 × 47 × 89 × 1103

**I divide it by:** 48th number, 12th, 11th, 10th and after that I can't get rid of the 17 so my answer is no, but it should be yes dividing by: 48th, 11th, 10th, 9th, 10th, 6th, 5th, 3*4th.

My 2nd idea is a little bit weird so that is why I wrote it. Is my solution correct? Or maybe there is another which can **determine if the number can be written as a product of Fibonacci numbers?** (Note that x can be really big)

Comment: @DanielHao It is yes, when you can write x as f1*f2*...*fn where fi= i-th Fibonacci number, and no when you can't. I don't know what do you mean writing "[165580141, 267914296]" the only input is one number. Edit: the Fibonacci numbers don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: Can you use the same Fibonacci number twice? For example if the input is 100, is the answer YES, because 100 = 2*2*5*5

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, you can. It is just like factorization into prime numbers but to Fibonacci numbers :)

Comment: The first thing to do is create a list of Fibonacci numbers that divide evenly into the target number. For your example, that list would be 2, 3, 5, 8, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 987, 46368, 4807526976. The next step is to factor `x` into prime factors, and check which prime factors are found in only one Fibonacci number. For example, the factor 17 only divides evenly into 34, so 34 must be part of the answer. When you get to the point where there are at least two choices for each factor, then you need to use a recursive backtracking algorithm to finish the job.

Comment: @user3386109 I just need a minute to process this idea. Could you tell me the estimated complexity of this idea?

Comment: [Relevant OEIS sequence.](http://oeis.org/A065108) The fact that Fibonacci numbers are a strong divisibility sequence should make a faster solution possible if you precompute prime factors of all small Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Inverse OEIS sequence: https://oeis.org/A065105

Answer (score 4):

Without relying on any special properties of Fibonnacci numbers, you could categorise this as a [coin change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) problem, where the available coins are the Fibonacci numbers, and the target must be achieved via multiplication instead of addition.

A solution is then to use a recursive algorithm combined with memoization to avoid the same subproblem to be solved repeatedly (principle of dynamic programming).

Here is a demo implementation in JavaScript, which runs the algorithm for the problem you mentioned in the question:

```js
// Preprocessing: collect all Fibonacci numbers with 15 digits or less:
let fib = [];
let a = 1, b = 2;
while (b < 1e16) {
    fib.push(b);
    [a, b] = [b, a+b];
}
fib.reverse(); // Put greatest Fib numbers first

let memo = new Map(); // For memoization
function solve(n, start=0) {
    if (n === 1) return true;
    let result = memo.get(n);
    if (result === undefined) { // Not in map:
        let i;
        for (i = start; i < fib.length; i++) {
            if (n % fib[i] == 0) {
                // Try solving problem after division by this factor:
                if (solve(n / fib[i], i)) break;
            }
        }
        result = i < fib.length;
        memo.set(n, result);
    }
    return result;
}

// Example input from question:
n = 2**10 * 3**5 * 5**2 * 7 * 11 * 17 * 23 * 47 * 89 * 1103
console.log(n, solve(n)); // 864126051784934400 true
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first idea is almost correct: a tiny modification makes it work. By [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_theorem), every Fibonacci number except 1, 8, and 144 has a prime divisor that does not divide any smaller Fibonacci number. Since 8 and 144 can both be written as the product of Fibonacci numbers themselves, we can ignore them when trying to find divisors.

```c
// Given: integer N
F <- [2, 3, 5, 8, 13...] // All Fibonacci numbers x, 1 < x <= N
F.reverse() // put in decreasing order

for x in F:
    if x == 8 or x == 144: continue
    while N % x == 0:
        N = N / x

return (N == 1)
```

Ignoring 8 and 144, this works because if `f` is the largest Fibonacci number dividing `N`, then `f` has a prime factor p that no earlier Fibonacci number has, so we have to divide `p` out of `N` as many times as possible if it is to be written as a product of Fibonacci numbers.

In fact, up to the isomorphism of replacing (8 with `2^3`) and (144 with `2^4 * 3^2` or `8 * 2 * 3^2`), this factorization has to be unique by that argument.